# how can i get the local image url to store in firebase

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have to store user profile photo in my firebase data base. I want to store a local image that has this path : "www/img/avatar.jpeg". I try this code to get image url

```
$scope.user.image="data:img/avatar.jpeg;base64"
```

But   when  running my code i get this message error : `ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME`.

Answer (score 0):

The user will have to select the photo, so you need a file selector in your HTML:

```
<input type="file" id="file" name="file" />
```

Then you can handle it in JavaScript with:

```
function handleFileSelect(e) {
  var file = e.target.files[0];
  // Get a reference to the location where we'll store our photos
  var storageRef = storage.ref().child('chat_photos');

  // Get a reference to store file at photos/<FILENAME>.jpg
  var photoRef = storageRef.child(file.name);
  // Upload file to Firebase Storage
  var uploadTask = photoRef.put(file);
  uploadTask.on('state_changed', null, null, function() {
    // When the image has successfully uploaded, we get its download URL
    var downloadUrl = uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL;
    // Set the download URL to the message box, so that the user can send it to the database
    textInput.value = downloadUrl;
  });
}
file.addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
```

This code comes from the [Zero To App talk at Google I/O](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xAsvwy1-oxE). Complete code is available in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/puf/8f67d3376d80ed2d02670d20bfc4ec7d).

Where it adds the download URL to a text box, you'll want to save it in the database.